# How to get property value from another property?

Tags: c#

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IReport
{
    int ReportId {get; set;}
}
```

I have an entity that has identity column property:

```
public int PaymentReportId {get; set;}
```

I need the `PaymentReport` to implement `IReport`

Inside my **PaymentReport.cs** I did:

```
public int PaymentReportId {get; set;}

public int ReportId {
    get => PaymentReportId; 
    set {} //no need to ever set this;
}
```

Otherwise the compiler was complaining about no setter implemented.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: The interface promises that the property *can* be set and yet your class breaks that promise. Remove the setter from the interface if you intend to implement read-only properties

Comment: If you intend to have *some* readonly and *some* get/set classes, you need different interfaces or properties for each one.

Comment: Look at Interface segregation principle...

Comment: @Karol Skrobot: I did not ask the obvious question. Do you really need the `PaymentReportId` property? Isn't the `ReportId` property enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to adhere to SOLID there is principle called interface segregation.

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

With your approach the principle is obviously violated as class `PaymentReport` does have property setter which is essentially not needed.

---

Consider to split the `IReport` to `IReportRead` and `IReportWrite` and implement only what is necessary.

```
public interface IReportRead
{
    int ReportId { get; }
}

public interface IReportWrite
{
    int ReportId { set; }
}

public class PaymentReport : IReportRead {//...}
```

That way you have clear abstraction and you are not polluting the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I removed, the set from the ReportId of IReport and then implemented in the class.

```
public interface IReport
{
    int  ReportId { get;  }
}

public class PaymentReport : IReport
{
    public int PaymentReportId { get; set; }
    public int ReportId
    {
        get => PaymentReportId;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaximilianAst my apology, I didn't explain. Provided more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the cleanest thing would be to change the interface or split into 
several interfaces. Here is an example of splitting interface into two and use them in both the `get` scenario and the `get, set` scenario:

```
interface IFooGet
{
    int Id { get; }
}

interface IFooSet
{
    int Id { set; }
}

public class FooGet : IFooGet
{
    public int Id { get; }
}

public class FooGetSet : IFooGet, IFooSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If that is not possible (maybe you don't own the code for the interface?) you might throw an exception if someone tries to call the property.

```
class PaymentReport : IReport
{
    public int PaymentReportId {get; set;}

    public int ReportId {
        get => PaymentReportId; 
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Just having a empty body in the `set` may sometime lead to error hiding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding if some code in the future tries to call setter and makes the assumption that the setter actually does something meaningful

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely MUST do this, well here you go...

```
//TODO: This is a terrible and kludgey way to do this and breaks rules of SOLID.
// This is only here to satisfy some runtime errors caused by messed up external cshtml references that we can't change at the moment.
// When we fix the external references we should remove this!
public long Id 
{ 
    get => Abs_Id;
    set => Abs_Id = value;
}
```

Comment: BTW the only reason I had to do this was because of a calling process that had many hidden incorrect references to this property that could not be found with a simple search and replace. This was the only backwards compatible way to fix the immediate issue while focusing on the change at hand. I left this TODO so that I could come back and fix it. Stuff like this haunts my dreams at night and it should haunt yours too. Don't do this unless...well you know the deal... -FS ;)